# Terminating multiprocessing.map on Exception

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm looking to launch several tests in parallel using multiprocessing:

```
 testlist=[test1, test2, test3]
 pool = ThreadPool(len(testlist))
 try:
      pool.map(run_test, testlist)
      print('Success')
      sys.exit(0)
 except Exception:
      print('FAILURE!')
      sys.exit(1)
```

Is there a way to get all the threads to terminate if one of them throws an exception?  It makes no sense to run all the tests if one fails early.

Answer (score 0):

You can't kill thread. Calling `pool.terminate()` will only prevent the creating of new thread.
The test already running will not be stopped.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/325528/7529716